# show excel file from internal share on Drupal page or module?

Tags: html, excel, drupal, share, intranet

I have a Intranet site that I created with drupal. I am trying to display a excel file from a share. Right now everytime the excel file is saved, its saved as a .html file and displayed by a basic page is drupal. The only down side is that the user needs to delete their browser history before they view the updated internal html excel file from a basic page.

I would think if their was a excel viewer that would automatically import and show the excel file in drupal WITHOUT any user control (user should not open excel file).

**So how can I show a excel file from a share, in ether .xls formant or .html format with out user needing to open file or clear browser ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The only down side is that the user needs to delete their browser
>   history before they view the updated internal html excel file from a
>   basic page.

Then what about setting the cache settings for that page to expire—and thus force that page to reload in the browser—more often than the rest of the site? Or heck, just don’t cache that specific page since this is an Intranet and it won’t get tons of traffic.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

More info [here](http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_cache_control).

Comment: The only issue is how would I get that tag into the html file? Excel saves it as a html file with tables inside. I don't want to edit all html file just to put this tag. Are you saying put the tag into the basic page? That might work.